# vscode and typescript template literal types

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, eslint, typescript-eslint

I'm having some problem trying to use the literal types in vsCcode. Using the example from the docs,

[image]

you can see that eslint is complaining about the code. (Parsing error: Type expected.eslint)

I have typescript 4.3.5 installed (using the vscode typescript version) , with version 1.52 of vsCode.

[image]

I also have tried adding a .eslintrc.json file with the contents

```
{
    "parserOptions": {
        "ecmaVersion": "latest",
        "sourceType": "module",
        "ecmaFeatures": {
            "jsx": true
        }
    },
    "rules": {
        "semi": "error"
    }
}
```

but nothing seems to remove the linting error

I have restarted vsCode, removed and reinstalled the eslint plugin

what else do I need to change / try ?

Comment: Oh, you have an eslint error. just install https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint

Comment: I already have these
info Direct dependencies
├─ @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin@4.28.4
├─ @typescript-eslint/parser@4.28.4
├─ eslint@7.31.0
└─ typescript@4.3.5

Comment: if I run eslint from the command line, it completes without error, so I'm starting to think it's something in the vsCode config

Comment: click on eslint button on bottom right corner. seem that your vscode using old version of eslint

Comment: [Info  - 7:04:38 AM] ESLint server is starting
[Info  - 7:04:38 AM] ESLint server running in node v14.16.0
[Info  - 7:04:38 AM] ESLint server is running.
[Info  - 7:04:38 AM] ESLint library loaded from: /workspace/node_modules/eslint/lib/api.js

Comment: oh, so I changed the version of node to be 16 instead of 14 and the problem seems to have been fixed in vsCode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem right now is that ESLint -which by default only understands JavaScript syntax- doesn't know how to parse TypeScript syntax.

From the comments thread, it seems you installed `@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin` and `@typescript-eslint/parser` as dependencies. That's the right start! But ESLint needs to be told to use them.

Set these properties in your ESLint config:

```js
module.exports = {
  // ...
  parser: '@typescript-eslint/parser',
  plugins: ['@typescript-eslint'],
  // ...
};
```

The docs for this are located at https://typescript-eslint.io/getting-started. That page will walk you through configuring ESLint to be able to parse TypeScript code, and with good sets of rules for TypeScript projects.